# How can I set a specific border around an element?

Tags: css

I want to put a specific border like below around my element.
How can I do this with css.

[image: Button with border]

I use this css for showing a border around an element:

```
.ui-selected {
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 1px 1px black; 
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 1px 1px black; 
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px 1px black;
}
```

But I want to show border like in the image. Is this possible?

I want to put those eight square around an element.

I use $('#element').addClass('ui-selected') to add
 and $('#element').removeClass('ui-selected') to remove.

I want css classes, is it possible

Comment: You want the grab-handles to be there as well, or just the dark/white borders?

Comment: Putting the grab handles is going to be difficult with just the border property.

Comment: I want to put those six square around an element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the solution:

```
box-shadow: 2px 2px 1px 0 #666;
border-top: 1px solid white;
border-left: 1px solid white;
```

You can see on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vGUre/).

Comment: You can still improve css/html defining classes to decrease the amount of css.

Comment: Thanks how can I decrease it... Can done this with one css declration

Comment: I use $('#element').addClass('ui-selected') to add and $('#element').removeClass('ui-selected') to remove.

I want css classes, is it possible

Comment: @AKZ I do not really understand your question, could be more specific please?

Comment: The real question is that can I do this with one css declare, which use in jquery addClass and removeClass.

Comment: It was not 100% clear to me, may be my difficulty with English. As I understand it, your objective is to do this via script, so I created one more update with 3 examples for you to see: http://jsfiddle.net/vGUre/3/

Answer (score 1):

You can specify a different colour for each side, using the border-(top|lef|right|bottom)-color property to add the highlights/shadows. The corners will be mitred accordingly.

[Border-top-color](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_border-top_color.asp)

You may then try to use individual CSS3 border images placed at the corners to acheive the black squares.

[border images](http://www.css3.info/preview/border-image/)

Answer (score 0):

For the drag handles: although you could [place them there with CSS](http://www.css3.info/preview/border-image/), you would not be able to attach event handlers to them, nor change the mouse cursor when it goes over them.

To get both of these, you need the dots to be actual elements. See [this example](http://phrogz.net/css/corners/index3.html) for one way to position corner elements. Cached for StackOverflow posterity (in the unlikely event that my site is down):

```
<html lang="en"><head>
  <title>Positioning Images</title>
  <style type="text/css">
    .compass          { position:relative }

    .compass .north,
    .compass .south,
    .compass .east,
    .compass .west,
    .compass .center  { width:15px; height:15px; position:absolute; left:50%; margin-left:-8px; top:50%; margin-top:-8px; cursor:pointer }

    .compass .north   { top:0; margin-top:0 }
    .compass .south   { bottom:0; top:auto; margin-top:0 }
    .compass .east    { right:0; left:auto; margin-left:0 }
    .compass .west    { left:0; margin-left:0 }
  </style>
</head><body>
  <div class="compass">
    <!-- your element here -->
    <img class="north west" src="c1.png" alt="resize">
    <img class="north east" src="c2.png" alt="resize">
    <img class="south east" src="c3.png" alt="resize">
    <img class="south west" src="c4.png" alt="resize">
    <img class="north" src="up.png" alt="resize">
    <img class="south" src="dn.png" alt="resize">
    <img class="east"  src="rt.png" alt="resize">
    <img class="west"  src="lt.png" alt="resize">
  </div>
</body></html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could experiment with pseudo elements:

```
div:after {
    content: '\25A0\25A0\25A0  \25A0\25A0\25A0  \25A0\25A0\25A0';
    position: absolute;
    top: -37px;
    left: -5px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 75px;
    letter-spacing: 67px;

}
```

​This looks good in Webkit, and is a few pixels off in Firefox.

[Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ojypf)